# Is it possible to count how many times a user has logged with wrong password or username

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am trying to display how many times renaming to log in to the system. But I did not reach to solution for this issue.

> This is the code

```
private void LogInUser(string username, string password)
{
  UserManager um = new UserManager();

  if (!um.ValidateUser(username, password))
  {
    um.loginCount = 5;
    lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
    um.loginCount --;
    lblErrorMessage.Text = "TAKE CARE, Invalid username or password you have  (" + um.loginCount + ") times remaining "; // mycbLanguage.GetMessage("InvalidUsernamePswrd");
    // SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are resetting your loginCount to 5 every time.  Move that line outside of the if() block and see if that helps.

Comment: I would suggest you to store this information into DB, so that you can still get the value even if your application restarts or crashes

Comment: What should happen if a user tries a certain number of times without reaching the lower limit and then retry again the next day? Did you want to reset and start again at 5 or you want to remember the number of earlier retries? And if you want to reset, how do you plan to memorize the last datetime of the failed attempts?

Comment: what happen is after 5 times with wrong login i locked the account and he must tell me to unlock the account , i want just warning him with remaining  times every time and if he insert correct username and password reset this counter to 5 again .

Comment: OK, but what if the user stops after 3 attempts and then retry the next day? You should remember your value (now 2)? If yes you need to store it in some kind of permanent storage and read it back at every attempts.

Comment: Yes you are right how can i do it ? where can i store it ? and check it every time

Answer (score 0):

**Use int variable to count this this**

//Use variable

```
    int i=5;
```

//code

```
    UserManager um = new UserManager();

        if (!um.ValidateUser(username, password))
        {
            i--;
            //um.loginCount = 5;
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            //um.loginCount --;
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "TAKE CARE, Invalid username or password you have  (" + i + ") times remaining "; // mycbLanguage.GetMessage("InvalidUsernamePswrd");
           // SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

            return;

        }
```

Comment: For each click give me 4 times , i want to count each time l  click to the login button with invalid username or password

Comment: Use this! 
declare the counter variable outside the function. Then it will show you perfect answer.

Comment: Please write it as answer or update your answer to be clear

Comment: Save it in a database and you will have many options. You can keep a record for troubleshooting when you discuss with the user.  You can save date, time and number of attempts the user has made.